# How to merged a column of list, extract unique string value, put into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Going crazy, cant figure out where went wrong.

> Have a file with dataframe, consist of single column, each row consist of 1 list

i am lost, please advice

```
fruits

0   ['apple', 'orange','grape']

1   ['apple','pineapple','coconut']
```

#

expected@

```
fruit

0   apple

1   coconut

2   grape

3   orange

4   pineapple
```

[link](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RQGAkD5Op3I/XXFQ8PM1JnI/AAAAAAAAjlM/MfYl0f-zGr45ocyR_aGLxStq7rGzQ7cswCLcBGAs/s1600/stack.png)

Comment: you just save half of my life, but how to keep only unique value?thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, already answered here. Lol, let me delete my answer then.

Comment: i tried both method, but stuck. pretty sure i done something wrong, but couldn't figure it out where. [link](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XE-Fs3p51wA/XXFXJG3eqFI/AAAAAAAAjlg/ieFnYyDa8SUeUNdqCD6NoEsF8hCt-_7aACLcBGAs/s1600/stack3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flatten your `data` into a single list first then read it as column in your DataFrame:

```
>>> data = [[['apple', 'orange','grape']],[['apple','pineapple','coconut']]]
>>> data = np.unique(np.ravel(data))
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit'])
>>> df
       fruit
0      apple
1    coconut
2      grape
3     orange
4  pineapple
```

### Edit for new case

Hi Jonathan, I replied to your email as to how you should go along with the entries if your column values if they are "like" lists. You need to use `ast.literal_eval()` on it.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'fruits': ['[\'apple\', \'orange\',\'grape\']','[\'apple\',\'pineapple\',\'coconut\']']})
>>> df
                            fruits
0      ['apple', 'orange','grape']
1  ['apple','pineapple','coconut']
```

Doing so however, you have to loop through the column, place every converted representation of your list into a `dummy_list` to gather everything into one list and do what you will in them.

```
>>> import ast
>>> dummy_list = []
>>> for i in range(0, len(df)):
...     dummy_list.extend(ast.literal_eval(df['fruits'][i]))
...
>>> dummy_list
['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'coconut']
```

Getting the unique value and creating the DataFrame you want:

```
>>> x = list(set(dummy_list))
>>> x
['orange', 'apple', 'grape', 'coconut', 'pineapple']
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['fruits 2.0'])
>>> df2
  fruits 2.0
0     orange
1      apple
2      grape
3    coconut
4  pineapple
```

Answer (score 1):

*np.ravel* alone (as *Anky* proposed) is not enough.
You need then to remove duplicates.
And if you are unhappy about non-continuous index, you are free to reset it.

So the complete code can be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ravel(data),columns=['fruit'])\
    .drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

*np.unique* (as in the other answer) has such a downside that it
**sorts** the source array. I suppose you want to keep the original order.

## Edit after your comment

It looks like you actually had a **DataFrame**, read using *read_excel()*,
looking like below:

```
                        fruits
0       [apple, orange, grape]
1  [apple, pineapple, coconut]
```

(not a list presented in your post).

To convert such a DataFrame to a single, flat list, you can run:

```
lst = df['fruits'].apply(pd.Series).stack().drop_duplicates().to_list()
```

It in an "ordinary" (*pythonic*) list.

To create a second DataFrame with a single column, run:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['fruits'])
```

**Another option**, without creation of an intermediate list:

```
df['fruits'].apply(pd.Series).stack().rename('fruits')\
    .drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
```

## Edit 2

I found a simpler solution, taking into account that *read_excel*
reads by default all cells as **strings**.

The key to success is *str.extractall* method, applied to *fruits* column.
To extract the text between apostrophes, the regex should be:

```
'(?P<fruits>[^']+)'
```

Details:

- `'` - An apostrophe (represents itself), before the text to match.
- `(?P<fruits>` - Start of a named capturing group (called also *fruits*).
- `[^']+` - The content of this group - a non-empty sequence of chars
  other than an apostrophe.
- `)` - End of the capturing group.
- `'` - Another apostrophe, after the text to match.

So if you run:

```
df.fruits.str.extractall(r"'(?P<fruits>[^']+)'")
```

you will get:

```
            fruits
  match           
0 0          apple
  1         orange
  2          grape
1 0          apple
  1      pineapple
  2        coconut
```

This result contains:

- A *MultiIndex*:

  - top level - the index of the source row (with no name),
  - second level - match number (0, 1 and 2 for each row).
- *fruits* - the name of the capturing group with individual strings
  in consecutive rows.

Now it remains only to drop duplicates and reset the index.

So the complete code, a **single** instruction is:

```
df.fruits.str.extractall("'(?P<fruits>[^']+)'")\
    .drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

The result is:

```
      fruits
0      apple
1     orange
2      grape
3  pineapple
4    coconut
```

Comment: i facing one last problem. the 'data' that i post, is a 'list', meaning type(data) equal list. But when I pd.read_excel, the data type become dataframe, where i am stuck. when I convert it to a list, the 'columns=['fruit']' will be lost. thus unable to extract unique value. please advice

Comment: In your post you didn't write about *read_excel*. So now it looks like you wanted to convert a **DataFrame** to a single column. Run *print(df)* from what you have read from Excel and add to your post.

Comment: fruits
0      ['apple', 'orange','grape']
1  ['apple','pineapple','coconut']

pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: sorry about didn't mention in beginning, as i want to post the 'data' without knowing the difference. \

But now, i am lost. after i [df = pd.read_excel], i follow up with your 'another option' code. the result is\ 

fruits
0 ['apple', 'orange','grape']
1 ['apple','pineapple','coconut']

which part did i miss?

Comment: *fruits* should be the name of (the only) column. Maybe in your *DataFrame* it is the first level of *MultiIndex*?

Comment: i have to show you [link](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RQGAkD5Op3I/XXFQ8PM1JnI/AAAAAAAAjlM/MfYl0f-zGr45ocyR_aGLxStq7rGzQ7cswCLcBGAs/s1600/stack.png)

Comment: it is different. [link](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-XE-Fs3p51wA/XXFXJG3eqFI/AAAAAAAAjlg/ieFnYyDa8SUeUNdqCD6NoEsF8hCt-_7aACLcBGAs/s1600/stack3.png)

Comment: The problem is that each cell contains not a list, but a string, composed of "[", 3 parts composed of a quote, a word and another quote, separated with commas and finally "]". You should convert such a string to a "proper" list and then apply my solution.

Comment: I was absent for past few days, but in this time I found a quite simple solution, just for your "lists" read as **strings**.